# IntelliJ Spring Boot - "Cannot resolve symbol 'JmsTemplate'" when creating a bean

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea, groovy, spring-jms

IntelliJ has been throwing "**Cannot resolve symbol 'JmsTemplate'**" for the past few days, when creating a jmsTemplate bean.

Here's my TestConfig.groovy file the error is thrown.

`

```
package automation.test

import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value
import org.springframework.boot.SpringBootConfiguration
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate

import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory

@SpringBootConfiguration
@EnableJms
class TestConfig {
    @Value('${activemq.host}')
    private String brokerUrl

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        activeMQConnectionFactory.setBrokerURL(brokerUrl)
        return activeMQConnectionFactory
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate() {
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate()
        jmsTemplate.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory())
        jmsTemplate.setReceiveTimeout(10000)
        return jmsTemplate;
    }
}
```

`

Here's my dependencies in build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.2.6.RELEASE"
    implementation "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:3.0.9"
    implementation "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-yaml:3.0.9"
    implementation "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.12"
    implementation group: "org.apache.activemq", name: "activemq-client", version: "5.15.12"
    implementation group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-jms', version: '6.0.3'

    implementation "com.oracle.database.jdbc:ojdbc10:19.3.0.0"

    testImplementation "org.spockframework:spock-core:2.0-M2-groovy-3.0"
    testImplementation "org.spockframework:spock-spring:2.0-M2-groovy-3.0"
    testImplementation "com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock-jre8:2.35.0"

    testImplementation "org.springframework:spring-tx:5.2.5.RELEASE"
    testImplementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.2.6.RELEASE"
    testImplementation "org.springframework:spring-jms:6.0.3"

    testImplementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.29'

    implementation group: 'javax.jms', name: 'javax.jms-api', version: '2.0.1'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.activemq', name: 'activemq-client', version: '5.16.0'

    implementation 'com.mashape.unirest:unirest-java:1.4.9'

    implementation 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2'
}
```

Here's the stacktrace.

```
> Task :generateMainEffectiveLombokConfig1
> Task :compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :compileGroovy
startup failed:
unable to resolve class org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate
 @ line 8, column 1.
   import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate
   ^
1 error
> Task :compileGroovy FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileGroovy'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 2s
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed
```

I've tried to resolve this using multiple techniques I managed to find online with no effect.

1. Delete the .idea folder and re-launch the project.
2. Invalidate caches and restart.
3. Re-installed the JDK and added it to the path
4. Made sure the correct SDK is set in the File->Project Structure settings.
5. Checked the Language Level of the modules and the Java Compiler.
6. Tried to add the @EnableJms

Nothing works and I don't understand why..

Comment: please add the full stacktrace you are getting

Comment: @AlexTbk Thanks, I've edited the post to include the stacktrace I'm getting.

Comment: just guessing: try adding this dependency
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jms -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.3</version>
</dependency>

Comment: @AlexTbk You are on the right path, however the 6.x.x version is what's breaking my code. I lowered it and now it's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the answer.

One of my dependencies had a version too high.

```
testImplementation "org.springframework:spring-jms:6.0.3"
```

Once I lowered the version to **5.3.24** it all started working fine.

```
testImplementation "org.springframework:spring-jms:5.3.24"
```

Comment: Thanks @Koedlt ! I need to wait another 23 hours until I mark my answer as accepted.